# No signature of method: static org.akhikhl.gretty.ProjectUtils.getClassPath()

Tags: gradle, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, gretty

I'm trying to migrate my javaee project from ant to gradle. My ultimate goal is to be able to run the project on jetty via gradle. I want to use gretty plugin for that. I'm using default gradle wrapper in Intellij IDEA CE 2018.1

When I start the appStart task of gretty I get the error :

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.akhikhl.gretty.ProjectUtils.getClassPath() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated, null, java.lang.String) values: [project ':myProject', null, runtime]
```

My projects directory structure is different from the default one expected by gradle. I checked the gretty source code and the exception comes from;

gretty/libs/gretty/src/main/groovy/org/akhikhl/gretty/StartBaseTask.groovy:212

```
resolvedClassPath.addAll(ProjectUtils.getClassPath(proj, wconfig.inplace, runtimeConfig))
```

The `wconfig.inplace` part returns `null`. I think I need to set something in my `build.gradle` file but I don't know what it is. Contents of my file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'ear'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'

repositories {
    jcenter()

    flatDir {
        dirs '../Libs'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src"]
        }

        resources {
            srcDir 'WebContent/resources'
        }
    }


    test{
        java {
            srcDirs=["test"]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // more dependencies...
}


gretty {
    httpPort = 8080
    contextPath = '/myProject'
    servletContainer = 'jetty9'
    webAppDirName = '/WebContent'
}
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Curious - can you reproduce this when running your project from CLI `./gradlew`, or only from IDEA?  And do you have a minimal shareable project which reproduces the problem from CLI?  Gradle version?  This does look like a bug BTW.

Comment: Yes I can. Also I can reproduce this by using the gradle's quickstart sample project at `gradle-4.9\samples\webApplication\quickstart` Strange enough same project runs without problem on a Linux box. But I get this error on Windows box.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Gretty bug.  Try adding an `inplace = false` to your config as a workaround:

```
gretty {
  servletContainer = 'jetty9.4'
  httpPort = 8080
  inplace = false
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. I will report a bug.